# Method to store a configuration file inside executable in C++

Tags: c++, configuration-files, embedded-resource

I need to store a configuration file that can be changed once the executable has been compiled inside of an executable using C++. I assume the configuration file would need to be stored as a resource for it to be editable once the executable has been compiled.

I have no idea how I can go about storing it as a resource and how to then include it in the main section of my project while still leaving it in the resource section.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This just sounds like an incredibly bad idea if it is intened to be used with any modern operating system. I haven't seen this used in practice since DOS and early embeded OSes.

Comment: It's Visual Studio C++ 2008, Windows XP+. I need to be able to distribute a single executable which has a custom configuration which can be controlled by another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows "*.ini" files is one way.

But, I suggest use XML files for configuration. Most compilers have 2 or 3 libraries to load & store data from XML files.

Besides, they allow to store information in a hierarchical way, and easy to add or remove configuration options.

EDIT:
Another way are JSON files.

Comment: XML should *never* be used for configuration, simply because XML is verbose and difficult for humans to edit.  It's also overkill: most programs need only a simple key-value store for their configuration, for which `.ini` files are a much better match.

Comment: @Zack I disagree. XML its a way to store configuration. I used to store binary encoded formats before. Of course there are other ways to store configuration, JSON, for example. Key-Value is good when its Hierarchical.

Comment: Lua could also be an option. There's a bit more work in it, but as it's basically a complete scripting language, it also provides more advanced features. Use it the simple way by just storing variables with a value assigned - or be more advanced by including code to calculate or process these variables.